# razor intellisense not working on VS2010 for microsoft.web.helpers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, intellisense

I have VS2010 Premium,.NET4.0, MVC3 Tools Update.

I've nugetted microsoft-web-helpers successfully.

I cannot get @razor intellisense to recognize the microsoft.web.helpers classes.

They do work correctely at runtime, i.e. @Twitter.profile shows a profile, but at design time the statent is seen as an error and no members are shown after "."

I've tried to add

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

to the

```
  <assemblies>
```

element in web.config, but it didn't help.

Any idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following in the `web.config` of the `Views` folder under the following section. After editing this, [restart Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109983/why-dont-my-html-helpers-have-intellisense/5110101#5110101).

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/> <!--This is the new entry-->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :) and I even didn't have to restart VS!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by selecting the "Use Visual Studio Development Server" on the project Properties page.