# MVC5 Custom helper doesn't recognize model type in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Using the following code:

```
public static IHtmlString RatingDropdown<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    int start, int max, int? current)
{
    var inputName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var select = new TagBuilder("select");

    select.MergeAttribute("name", inputName);
    foreach (var rating in Enumerable.Range(start, max))
    {
        var option = new TagBuilder("option");
        option.MergeAttribute("value", rating.ToString());
        option.SetInnerText(rating.ToString());

        if ((current ?? -1) == rating)
        {
            option.MergeAttribute("selected", "true");
        }

        select.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
    }

    return new HtmlString(select.ToString());
}
```

The namespace of the class the code above resides in has been added to ~/Views/web.config as necessary, but I've also tried an explicit @using statement in the view. Neither seems to matter.

When I try to type the code in the view, I get the following:

[image]

Notice the type of the `x` parameter in the intellisense window - TModel. When I use one of the built in html helpers, it resolves correctly to the model of my view, as so:

[image]

In the latter case, intellisense works for all my model's properties as expected, but in the former, it breaks down, presumably because intellisense cannot figure out the type for `x` so it cannot resolve the type's properties. Why is intellisense not picking this information up?

***EDIT:*** I posted an explanation of my solution to the problem below, but it's not really an answer because it's absolutely not valid for some cases. This seems like a visual studio bug to me.

Comment: after you added the namespace to your config file.. did you close all of your views and reopen them?

Comment: Yes of course. I tried closing everything and reopening, closing VS and reopening, deleting the .vs directory and reopening, etc.

Comment: Could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109983/why-dont-my-html-helpers-have-intellisense

Comment: Nope, I found a solution (see my posted answer below) but I'd be VERY curious as to whether this is intended design or a VS bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite stupid. I'm not sure if it's a bug in VS, or if it's intended and just not referenced anywhere, but in order for intellisense to pick up my method, I had to add an overload that accepted only the HtmlHelper and Expression parameters, i.e.

```
public static IHtmlString RatingDropdown<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    return RatingDropdown(htmlHelper, expression, 1, 5, null);
}
```

Doing nothing else than adding this overloaded method fixed the intellisense problem (without even reloading the razor file, I might add).

Further experimentation reveals that I can add additional parameters to the signature, so long as the parameters have default values, e.g.

```
public static IHtmlString RatingDropdown<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    int start = 1, int max = 5)
{
    return RatingDropdown(htmlHelper, expression, start, max, -1);
}
```

The following, however, does not work:

```
public static IHtmlString RatingDropdown<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string testParameter)
{
    return RatingDropdown(htmlHelper, expression, 1, 5, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the project name when adding the namespace in web.config file:

> `<add namespace="MyProject.HelperNamespace" />`

Or might be after restarting the Visial Studio, it will work.

Comment: In C#, the Project name is the namespace root. This sounds like an answer geared toward VB developers where the project being part of the namespace may not always be obvious.